# Is there a better approach to update complex interfaces so that changes reflect in view

Tags: react-redux

How do I update a complex interface as props in the views after it is being updated in the store?

In the following case, I am trying to do a validation in the reducer.  Based on the validation, I have to update the label and the error message. Though the store is being updated, I can`t see the update in the view. Also, when I type in, I can`t see the text on my screen, though they are sent to the store?

**RegistrationForm.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Input } from 'src/FormUtilities/Input';
import { IUserProps } from '../userEntitities';

interface IProps{
    user:IUserProps
    onChange:(name:string, value:string)=>void
}

export const RegistrationForm =(props:IProps) =>{

        return(
            <div>
                <Input name={props.user.FirstName.Name}                
                 label= {props.user.FirstName.Name}
                 placeholder= ''
                 value=''
                 onChange={props.onChange}
                 error= {props.user.FirstName.ErrorMessage} />

                  <Input name={props.user.Email.Name}                
                 label= {props.user.Email.Name}
                 placeholder= ''
                 value=''
                 onChange={props.onChange}
                 error= {props.user.Email.ErrorMessage} />
            </div>
        )

    }
```

---

**actions.ts**

```
    import * as actionsEnums  from './actionEnums';

    interface IUpdateField{    
        type: actionsEnums.FIELD_CHANGED,
        value: string,
        name:string
    }
    export const updateField = (name:string, value:string):IUpdateField => ({ 
        'name' : name,
        type: actionsEnums.FIELD_CHANGED,     
        'value': value     
    });

export type UserAction = IUpdateField
```

---

**reducer.ts**

```
import * as constants from './actionEnums';
import {UserAction} from './actions'
import { IField } from './userEntitities';

export interface IUserState {
    user:{
        Email:IField,
        FirstName: IField 
    }  
}
export const setDefaultUserState:() => IUserState = () => ({
    user: {
      Email: {
        ErrorMessage: '',
        Label:'Email',
        Name:'Email',            
        Text: ''
      },       
      FirstName: {
        ErrorMessage: '',
        Label:'Name',
        Name:'Name',            
        Text: ''
      },
    }}
  )

export const userRegistrationReducer = (state= setDefaultUserState(), action:UserAction):IUserState =>{
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case constants.FIELD_CHANGED:
            return validateField(state, action.name, action.value)

        default: return state
    }
}

const validateField = (state: IUserState, name:string, value:string) => {

   if(name==='Name')
   {
       if(value===''){
        return {

                ...state, FirstName: { ...state.user.FirstName, ErrorMessage: "Invalid name" } }

        }
    }
   if(name==='Email'){
        if (!value.includes("@"))
        {
                return{
                    ...state,ErrorMessage:'Invalid Email', Label:'Email *' 
                }

        }
    }
    return {
        ...state
    }

  };
```

---

**RegistrationContainer**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { IState } from 'src/Redux lessons';
import {updateField, UserAction} from './actions'
import {RegistrationForm} from './Components/RegistrationForm'


const mapStateToProps = (state:IState)=>
({
        user: state.userRegistrationReducer.user
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<UserAction>)=>{
    return {
        onChange:(name:string, value:string)=>dispatch(updateField(name, value))
    }
}

export const RegistrationFormContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RegistrationForm)
```

---

**index.ts**

```
import { combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {IUserState, userRegistrationReducer} from '../Registration/reducers'
import { IUserColorState, userReducer} from './Lesson4/redux/userColorReducer'

export interface IState{
    userRegistrationReducer : IUserState,
    userReducer:IUserColorState
}

export const reducers = combineReducers<IState>({
    userReducer,
    userRegistrationReducer,    
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! I just see the pb.
Always add current typed state in inputs value.
Example:

```
<Input name={props.user.FirstName.Name} 
label= {props.user.FirstName.Name} 
placeholder= '' 
value={props.user.Email.Text} 
onChange={props.onChange} 
error= {props.user.FirstName.ErrorMessage} 
/>
```

Maybe you don't need to include every typed letter to the reducer to optimize performance.

You could do this: Current typed data in state, then send the data via an onClick button.
use onChange to reducer only if you want to get immediate result for each typing letter

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the data without the validation logic, the reducer is working or not?

test this for example:

```
export const userRegistrationReducer = (state= setDefaultUserState(), action:UserAction):IUserState =>{
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case constants.FIELD_CHANGED:
            return action.name

        default: return state
    }
}
```

Comment: The reducer is working.  When I type in the textboxes, I can`t see anything but the typed value is passed to the reducer.

Comment: Ah! I just see the pb, your input value should get the actual typed values.
Example:
<Input name={props.user.FirstName.Name}                
                 label= {props.user.FirstName.Name}
                 placeholder= ''
                 value=''userRegistrationReducer.user.Email.Text"
                 onChange={props.onChange}
                 error= {props.user.FirstName.ErrorMessage} 
/>